# Unable to correctly read bmp file

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to read certain information from a bmp file. Basically file type i.e B M in my bmp file.   I start with first opening the file. Which is happening correctly. The first fread is however failing.   Why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 1

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fd = NULL;
    char buff[2];
   unsigned int i=0,size=0,offset=0;
    memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));

    fd = fopen("RIT.bmp","r+");

    if(NULL == fd)
    {
        printf("\n fopen() Error!!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n File opened successfully\n");

    if(SIZE*2 != fread(buff,SIZE,2,fd))//to read the file type.(i. e. B M)
    {
        printf("\n first fread() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
 File opened successfully

 first fread() failed
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Update**

Yes the file is empty, due to some earlier error. That is why this error is coming.

Comment: Wouldn't you still want to open (and read) it as a binary file?

Comment: How many bytes did it read? How many are in the file? (You might get less than you asked for if you hit eof) This is more C than C++. Don't forget to close the file. Have you tried checking errno or ferror? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror

Comment: It might be helpful to print out the actual result of fread.

Comment: And please do not call a `FILE*` `fd`... that confuses me any time I read it (`fd` is conventionally a file descriptor, i.e. a small int).

Comment: A BMP file is an image file that can contain control characters.  Thus it should be opened as a binary file (`"rb"`), not as a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file doesn't have enough(2 bytes) data. Its giving correct output when I checked with file> 2 bytes. Same is failing for empty file

Comment: Yes, The main file got corrupted.

Comment: if my answer helped you, then please dont forget to vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html): "Upon successful completion, fread() shall return the **number of elements successfully read** [...]."

That would be 2, not `SIZE*2`.

Although, at second thought, `SIZE` is 1, so while the program is error-prone, it is not actually wrong. In that case, the second part of the sentence applies: " ... which is less than nitems only if a read error or end-of-file is encountered.". And as others said, check the global `errno` if the file is long enough. Maybe it's time for a new SSD.